# How can I send a POST request with a web browser?

Tags: http, browser, post

How can I send a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request with a web browser?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797534/how-do-i-manually-fire-http-post-requests-with-firefox-or-chrome/29419094#29419094

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because it does not request an extension or a tool but specifically limits to browser only. Which yielded the superb answer by [@oezi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3307401/8080472)

Comment: This also isn't a duplicate because this question was asked before the referenced question.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

With a form, just set `method` to `"post"`:

```
<form action="blah.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="data" value="mydata" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Or you can use Chrome Poster ( https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-poster/cdjfedloinmbppobahmonnjigpmlajcd ) or Firefox Poster ( https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/poster/ ) extentions, if the purpose is testing.

Comment: thank you! this was my only resort because I can't download useful extensions like "Postman"  at my workplace.

Answer (score 14):

You can create an HTML page with a form, having method="post" and action="yourdesiredurl" and open it with your browser.

As an alternative, there are some browser plugins for developers that allow you to do that, like *Web Developer Toolbar* for Firefox.